# FOR LOOP in windows cmd and batch file not working

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to call a batch file that runs a `for` loop and calls a second script:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`dir/b /o:d %partionHome%\tmp\queue\*.t~#`) do %partitionHome%\conf\SQLLoader\SQL_Loader_%DSNname%\Script.bat %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %%i %has_prefix% %partionHome%
```

`Script.bat` never runs; I've tried adding do `call` but i believe this gets ignored with `FOR /F`, I just cannot get the loop to call the script. All parameters are available and paths etc. are correct?

Comment: Does this work when you run it from a command line?  `%partitionHome%\conf\SQLLoader\SQL_Loader_%DSNname%\Script.bat %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %%i %has_prefix% %partionHome%`  I would imagine the `%1 %2 ... %7` isn't right, as those are meaningless arguments here... unless this is part of a bigger script and you've left out the parameters that are being passed into this subroutine.

Comment: @Stephan - He has the USEBACKQ option, so the back-ticks are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DIR command is probably not returning anything, so there is nothing for FOR /F to iterate.

Looks to me like you have a spelling mistake: `%partionHome%` vs. `%partitionHome%`.

Also, make sure your variables `partitionHome` and `DSNname` are defined properly.

The CALL is definitely needed (once you fix the other problems)

Lastly, you should enclose your paths in quotes, just in case there are spaces and/or poison characters within the value.

```
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`dir/b /o:d "%partitionHome%\tmp\queue\*.t~#"`) do call "%partitionHome%\conf\SQLLoader\SQL_Loader_%DSNname%\Script.bat" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 "%%I" %has_prefix% "%partitionHome%"
```